# Constant drain on battery solution

Tags: electrical, ford, battery, battery-drain, fusion

I have a 2012 Ford Fusion SE. My problem is that my dc power outlets  (cigarette lighter) are on continuously. I was charging one of my cell phone battery packs and as I unplugged it I noticed that the light on my dc to USB adapter was still lit, meaning that power was still on the line from the battery pack.

I was wondering if I left that plugged in, will it compensate for the constant drain of something small like a radar detector?

Comment: Welcome to Mechanics SE!  Will what compensate?  I don't get the question.  Anything plugged in _will_ drain the battery, it's just a matter of how fast it drains.

Comment: Also, are you sure it isn't just on for a period of time then shuts off? In some vehicle (not sure on the Fusion), the cigarette lighter will only stay hot for 15 minutes after your vehicle is shut off. This is controlled by the Body Control Module (BCM), just like the radio, wipers, and windows may work after you turn off the key until you open a door.

Comment: They do not shut off after 15 minutes. I have accidentally left stuff plugged in before and it was still on when I got back into the car.

Answer (score 1):

No, the system has no ability to compensate for drain, however small, if the engine is not running.  Therefore I would recommend removing anything from the power outlet if the car is parked up.  Even the smallest drain (such as an interior light left on) will eventually drain the battery and prevent the car from starting.

Comment: But what about devices such as solar panels that plug into the outlets stating that they will compensate for a small drain? (Example: http://www.gandermountain.com/modperl/product/details.cgi?pdesc=Wagan-Solar-Power-Battery-Charger&i=440373&r=view&cvsfa=2586&cvsfe=2&cvsfhu=343430333733&gclid=CjwKEAiAp_WyBRD37bGB_ZO9qAYSJAA72IkgZ9o07NzHxRAUgkgXmCuKC_0vqGDoH7w9ypJaZ9_FwRoCSqPw_wcB )

Comment: A solar panel is providing, not drawing charge.

Comment: Yes, a solar panel charger should compensate for a small drain, if that is what you are asking.